# Is there a way to set up a ‘rain’ of cubes (randomly varying in size, starting location etc.) to fall one after the other?

Tags: animation, objects, particles

I would like a steady stream of cubes of different scales, starting positions, and rotations to fall one after the other for at least a minute. Is there a way to set this up without manually placing 1000 cubes above my scene and timing their individual falls?

(All cubes will also be rigid bodies and will be interacting with one another as they land, ultimately ending up in a big pile.)

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to see questions about [particles] which can generate cubes  or other meshes ... of different sizes and scales and positions.  These can interact as rigid bodies.  There are many tutorials on [particles] on the famous video website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  The emitters of those meshes can fully or partially determine the starting location of the cube meshes.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger thanks for replying. I’ve never used particles before and completely forgot about them/didn’t know all the ways they can be used. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: There are no dump questions ... only dump past presidents of certain countries .. who know nothing about Blender.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger  you do realize you put a "p"  instead of a "d" at the end of the word "dumb".  in-fact, you did it twice.